# Rename Column/Field Name in an access MDB table

Tags: python, ms-access

Is it possible to use python to rename an existing field/column name in an Access MDB Table?  I have access installed on a system and I am using python 2.6.  Other options and ideas gladly accepeted.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This comes close:

[Add new field to access table using python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4370274/add-new-field-to-access-table-using-python)

Check yourself if you can rename a column on the SQL level.